# Amazon Elasticsearch - Concurrent Bulk Requests

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert

When I am adding 200 documents to ElasticSearch via one bulk request - it's super fast.

But I am wondering if is there a chance to speed up the process with **concurrent executions**: 20 concurrent executions with 10 documents each.

I know it's not efficient, but maybe there is a chance to speed up the process with concurrent executions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lower concurrency is preferable for bulk document inserts. Some concurrency is helpful in some circumstances — It Depends™ and I'll get into it — but is not a major or automatic win.

There's a lot that can be tuned when it comes to performance of writes to Elasticsearch. One really quick win that you should check: are you using HTTP keep-alive for your connections? That's going to save a lot of the TCP and TLS overhead of setting up each connection. Just that change can make a big performance boost, and also uncover some meaningful architectural considerations for your indexing pipeline.

So check that out and see how it goes. From there, we should go to the bottom, and work our way up.

The index on disk is Lucene. Lucene is a segmented index. The *index* part is a core reason why you're using Elasticsearch in the first place: a dictionary of sorted terms can be searched in O(log N) time. That's super fast and scalable. The segment part is because inserting into an index is not particularly fast — depending on your implementation, it costs O(log N) or O(N log N) to maintain the sorting.

So Lucene's trick is to buffer those updates and append a new segment; essentially a collection of mini-indices. Searching some relatively small number of segments is still much faster than taking all the time to maintain a sorted index with every update. Over time Lucene takes care of *merging* these segments to keep them within some sensible size range, expunging deleted and overwritten docs in the process.

In Elasticsearch, every shard is a distinct Lucene index. If you have an index with a single shard, then there is very little benefit to having more than a single concurrent stream of bulk updates. There may be some benefit to concurrency on the application side, depending on the amount of time it takes for your indexing pipeline to collect and assemble each batch of documents. But on the Elasticsearch side, it's all just one set of buffers getting written out to one segment after another.

Sharding makes this a little more interesting.

One of Elasticsearch's strengths is the ability to *partition* the data of an index across multiple shards. This helps with availability, and it helps workloads scale beyond the resources of a single server.

Alas it's not quite so simple as to say that the concurrency should be equal, or proportional, to the number of primary shards that an index has. Although, as a rough heuristic, that's not a terrible one.

You see, internally, the first Elasticsearch node to handle the request is going to turn that Bulk request into a sequence of individual document update actions. Each document update is sent to the appropriate node that is hosting the shard that this document belongs to. Responses are collected by the bulk action so that it can send a summary of the bulk operation in its response to the client.

So at this point, depending on the document-shard routing, some shards may be busier than others during the course of processing an incoming bulk request. Is that likely to *matter?* My intuition says not really. It's possible, but it would be unusual.

In most tests and analysis I've seen, and in my experience over ~ten years with Lucene, the slow part of indexing is the transformation of the documents' values into the inverted index format. Parsing the text, analyzing it into terms, and so on, can be very complex and costly. So long as a bulk request has sufficient documents that are sufficiently well distributed across shards, the concurrency is not as meaningful as saturating the work done at the shard and segment level.

When tuning bulk requests, my advice is something like this.

- Use HTTP keep-alive. This is not optional. (You are using TLS, right?)
- Choose a batch size where each request is taking a modest amount of time. Somewhere around 1 second, probably not more than 10 seconds.
- If you can get fancy, measure how much time each bulk request took, and dynamically grow and shrink your batch.

A durable queue unlocks a lot of capabilities. If can fetch and assemble documents and insert them into, say, Kafka, then that process can be run in parallel to saturate the database and parallelize any denormalization or preparation of documents. A different process then pulls from the queue and sends requests to the server, and with some light coordination you can test and tune different concurrencies at different stages. A queue also lets you pause your updates for various migrations and maintenance tasks when it helps to put the cluster into read-only mode for a time.

I've avoided replication throughout this answer because there's only one reason where I'd ever recommend tweaking replication. And that is when you are bulk creating an index that is not serving any production traffic. In that case, it can help save some resources through your server fleet to turn off all replication to the index, and enable replication after the index is essentially done being loaded with data.

To close, what if you crank up the concurrency anyway? What's the risk? Some workloads don't control the concurrency and there isn't the time or resources to put a queue in front of the search engine. In that case, Elasticsearch can avoid a fairly substantial amount of concurrency. It has fairly generous thread pools for handling concurrent document updates. If those thread pools are saturated, it will reject responses with a HTTP 429 error message and a clear message about queue depths being exceeded. Those can impact stability of the cluster, depending on available resources, and number of shards in the index. But those are all pretty noticeable issues.

Bottom line: no, 20 concurrent bulks with 10 documents each will probably not speed up performance relative to 1 bulk with 200 documents. If your bulk operations are fast, you should increase their size until they run for a second or two, or are problematic. Use keep-alive. If there is other app-side overhead, increase your concurrency to 2x or 3x and measure empirically. If indexing is mission critical, use a fast, durable queue.

Comment: Disclosure/credentials — I'm the founder and an operator behind https://bonsai.io/ which was the original managed Elasticsearch service on AWS, and which is where I get my experience with these things!

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight answer to this as it depends on lots of factors. Above the optimal bulk request size, performance no longer improves and may even drop off. The optimal size, however, is not a fixed number.

It depends entirely on your hardware, your document size and complexity, and your indexing and search load.

Try indexing typical documents in batches of increasing size. When performance starts to drop off, your batch size is too big.

Since you are doing it in batches of 200, the chances are high that it should be most optimal way to index. But again it will depend on the factors mentioned above.