# Elasticsearch indexing multiple files in parallel

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, parallel-processing, lucene

I'm trying to index multiple files in ES. Since there are many files and each file has its own index, sequential indexing seems to be slow in production usage. What I would like is to index multiple files in parallel. Let's say I have 100 files and would like to index 10 files at a time and complete indexing in 10 batches. I was expecting the time taken by 10 files to index and a single file to index be the same since they are executing in parallel and resources are also enough. However, on the ES side, indexing is being done sequentially and the time required to index 10 files is almost 10 times the time required by a single file.

It seems like ES indexing runs sequentially although parallel requests are sent for indexing from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327480/amazon-elasticsearch-concurrent-bulk-requests). Is it possible to index data in parallel to reduce indexing time or am I missing something here? Thanks for the help

Note: I am testing this in a single node setup. Can that be an issue?

Comment: How much files are you indexing to see a performance loss?

Comment: Indexing 10 files serially and indexing 10 files in parallel is taking the almost same time. I was expecting for the time to reduce while working in parallel

Comment: 10 files is nothing, if you want to see a results you should try to index 1 000 000 files or at least 100k. I was using elk on production and i didn't see a slow indexing with 5-10 million files. But doing anything on one node with elk is misunderstanding. They even say that for it to work best you need at least 3 nodes. So can you tell me what you mean by indexing taking long time? becouse maybe you are just doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided the code and your performance test numbers, so it's difficult to guess, where you are making a mistake, I am guessing **you are sending 10 different index request simultaneously when you are saying parallel request** which is not the right way, you should instead use the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) which is the right choice for your setup.

if you are already using the Bulk API, please provide all the relevant information required to debug the issue further.

Comment: Regarding numbers: I am indexing 60 files in a batch and it takes around 50 seconds to index. Each file has its own index and that is done using bulk indexing. To simulate the simultaneous case, I tried creating similar 10 groups and send the index request in parallel. That is taking close to 500 seconds. I was expecting that too to complete in 50 seconds or so.

Comment: @prms so you are using bulk api, correct? could you please provide your code, also how you making sure that ES is not becoming bottlneck?

Comment: I am using Python ES wrapper. I'll have to write the sample code to share. To send parallel requests I am using Python ray framework. I experimented by testing individual steps of code in parallel. Preprocessing, index and search were divided into individual units and were sent in parallel. Except for indexing, other operations show time gain. Indexing is the only one to show multiplicative timing. Can you point me to resources that to learn about indexing multiple indices in parallel? Regarding code, I'll share with you after some time

Comment: @prms for write operation ES uses the write threadpool as mentioned in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html when you are running the test make sure this queue is not getting full, also size of its increased to 10k recently.